# Rails where or select for query chaining

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So when querying a database, I know it's much better to use `where` on the initial query like so:

```
pending = Request.where("status = ?", "Pending").order! 'created_at DESC'
```

However, if I need to further filter this information, I can do it with either `where` or `select`:

```
high_p = pending.where("priority = ?", "High Priority")
normal_p = pending.where("priority = ?", "Priority")
```

Or

```
high_p = pending.select{|x| x.priority == "High Priority"}
normal_p = pending.select{|x| x.priority == "Priority"}
```

My question is which of these is better from a performance standpoint? Should we always use `where`? Or does `select` have a use case when the whole database isn't being searched?

Comment: It's almost always better to let the db do as much of the work as possible. Only use select when you absolutely have to, for some special cases. At least that's my opinion on this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`where` is much better from a performance standpoint.  `where` modifies the SQL so that the DB does the "heavy lifting" of identifying records to retrieve.

`select` retrieves all records that meet the initial `where` condition, converts them into an array, and uses `Array#select' so the selection is happening at the rails end and you've retrieved more records from the db than you needed and done more processing than is necessary.

Select does have an advantage in that you can select based on model methods that may not be simply extracted from table columns. For example you may have a model method `#bad_credit?` which is determined by, say, a credit limit, age if outstanding invoices, and type of account.