# Rails: How do I filter a ActiveRecord collection result without making new db queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I have a `Candle` model with '`today`' scope. The scope runs a few heavy conditions and gives me around 5k rows as the result.

```
today_candles = Candle.today
```

I want to later filter this collection with a column value. For eg:

```
aaa_candles = today_candles.where(type: 'AAA')
bbb_candles = today_candles.where(type: 'BBB')
...
```

**But** each of this filter is making a new db request as follows:

```
Candle.today.where(type: 'AAA')
Candle.today.where(type: 'BBB')
...
```

Is there a way to filter on the initial collection `today_candles` data without making new multiple db requests? It feels like a basic functionality but I cannot find it.

I am currently storing the collection as an array and then looping through them to filter and avoid multiple db calls. But this feels stupid.

*Please note:* I'm not sure if Rails does cache the AR collection and filter them without new db_queries in a production environment. I'm currently on webrick (development).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails where or select for query chaining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448821/rails-where-or-select-for-query-chaining)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to filter later - just treat relation as array. For example, filter with select:

```
today_candles.select { |x| x.type == 'AAA' }
```

Comment: Thank you igor. I found this great question and answer that explains the nuances very well. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42449522/1486597